# Can`t compile wxWidget application for MacOSX

Tags: macos, wxwidgets

I am trying to compile an application for WxWidgets using wxWidgets 2.9.3. I compiled the same source under Linux pretty fine and I think the main error is :

```
#error "Carbon does not support 64bit"
```

and I did not get how to set this correctly.
to compile I used the follow command:

```
g++ hellomac.cpp -o hellomac `/opt/bin/wx-config --cxxflags --libs`
```

Could someone help me on this?
/opt/bin is where my wxWidget is installed. My OSX is version 10.6.8

Answer (score 7):

A while ago on Snow Leopard I used the following configuration settings to build wxWidgets for OSX:

`../configure --with-cocoa --with-macosx-version-min=10.6 --enable-unicode --disable-shared --enable-debug --enable-universal-binaries`

The important options are `--with-cocoa`and `--enable-universal-binaries` to make it work under 64bit OSX.

After this just do `make` to compile wxWidgets again.

Be aware there could be an older version of wxWidgets in `/opt/bin/`. Because of new wxWidget upgrades I prefer to put the compiled version of wxWidgets in my home folder to keep an eye on all files. If you install it in your system paths you might lose the overview. Now it could happen you're not using the wx-config version you wanted to use.

To compile your own wxWidget apps I recommend to create your own Makefile.
Your compiling command looks already good, but let me give you an advice. After `--libs` try using flags like `core` and `base` to keep save all OSX Frameworks will be added to your compilation.

Here a simple Makefile example you can use if you want to. It also creates an OSX executable.

```
APP = $(shell basename $(shell pwd))

CC = g++

CFLAGS = -Wall `wx-config --cppflags`
LFLAGS = `wx-config --libs core,base`

BUIDIR = build
OBJDIR = obj
OSXDIR = osx
SRCDIR = src

SOURCES := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.cpp)
OBJECTS := $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%,%,$(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(SOURCES)))

NO_COLOR = \033[0m
O1_COLOR = \033[0;01m
O2_COLOR = \033[32;01m

PREFIX = "$(O2_COLOR)==>$(O1_COLOR)"
SUFFIX = "$(NO_COLOR)"


all: clean linking osx
   @echo $(PREFIX) Build finished $(SUFFIX)

clean:
   @echo $(PREFIX) Cleaning up $(SUFFIX)
   rm -rfv $(BUIDIR) $(OBJDIR)

$(BUIDIR)/:
   mkdir -p $@

$(OBJDIR)/:
   mkdir -p $@

%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp
   @echo $(PREFIX) Compiling $< $(SUFFIX)
   $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $(OBJDIR)/$@

linking: $(BUIDIR)/ $(OBJDIR)/ $(OBJECTS)
   @echo $(PREFIX) Linking $(SUFFIX)
   $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJDIR)/*.o -o $(BUIDIR)/$(APP) $(LFLAGS)

osx: $(BUIDIR)/$(APP) $(OSXDIR)/Info.plist
   @echo $(PREFIX) Creating Mac OS X executable file $(SUFFIX)
   -mkdir $(BUIDIR)/$(APP).app
   -mkdir $(BUIDIR)/$(APP).app/Contents
   -mkdir $(BUIDIR)/$(APP).app/Contents/MacOS
   -mkdir $(BUIDIR)/$(APP).app/Contents/Resources
   -mkdir $(BUIDIR)/$(APP).app/Contents/Resources/English.lproj
   cp $(OSXDIR)/Info.plist $(BUIDIR)/$(APP).app/Contents/
   @#cp $(OSXDIR)/version.plist $(APP).app/Contents/
   @#cp $(OSXDIR)/InfoPlist.strings $(APP).app/Contents/Resources/English.lproj/
   @#cp $(OSXDIR)/Icons.icns AnotherResource.txt $(APP).app/Contents/Resources/
   cp $(BUIDIR)/$(APP) $(BUIDIR)/$(APP).app/Contents/MacOS/$(APP)
   echo -n 'APPL????' > $(BUIDIR)/$(APP).app/Contents/PkgInfo

.PHONY: all clean linking osx
.SILENT: $(BUIDIR)/ $(OBJDIR)/
```

Comment: lunij, first of all Sorry for taking so long. I didn't have Mac the whole weekend. Thanks for the clue and the make advice. I am (re)compilling wxWidgets right now. later I will try with an edit version of your make. Best regards, ABR

Comment: This worked quite well upto the compilation and linking step with gcc49 installed with macport.  However the osx step did not work and terminated with the error "No rule to make target `osx/Info.plist', needed by `osx'.  Stop." Is there a standard way to generate the Info.plist file without having to create and use a Xcode project?